# Raspberry pi:sudo is not working

Tags: python, windows, putty, raspberry-pi3

I have logged into raspberry pi via SSH. I m getting error while run any command with sudo in raspberry pi3. Eroor is like sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set.So i dont know how to set it and this error is about what? If root user require than plz tell me what is root user and how to logged into root user in raspberry pi3 via SSH?plz help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Login with root

```
su -
```

and

```
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```